# Connection between two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix and B be another $n\times n$ matrix. Each row vector of the matrix $A$ contains at least one eigenvalues of the matrix $B$ without repetition then what is the connection between the matrix $A$ and $B$?

Comment: You have to show your work, or what you have tried and failed. Also it's not clear what you are asking, what is a 'connection' between two matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised if there is any useful "connection" between $A$ and $B$. Suppose $B$ is the identity matrix. Then every row of $A$ contains a $1$. There are many matrices with this property.